# PHP: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/

Tags: php, file, permissions, upload

I keep getting this error on a new server I just setup

```
[Wed Feb 16 22:46:51 2011] [error] [client 71.1.236.114] PHP Warning:  
move_uploaded_file(upload/110216104651_00134_smooth_1440x900.jpg): 
failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/admin/_application/models/Roles.model on line 1757, 
referer: http://nacc.biz/admin/admin/modifyarticle.php?roleid=4
[Wed Feb 16 22:46:51 2011] [error] [client 71.1.236.114] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file():
Unable to move '/tmp/php6wlOg1' to    'upload/110216104651_00134_smooth_1440x900.jpg' 
in /var/www/admin/_application/models/Roles.model on line 1757, referer:
http://nacc.biz/admin/admin/modifyarticle.php?roleid=4
[Wed Feb 16 22:46:51 2011] [error] [client 71.1.236.114] PHP Notice:  
Upload Error: Error moving from temp dir in /var/www/admin/_application/models/Roles.model on line 1759,
referer: http://nacc.biz/admin/admin/modifyarticle.php?roleid=4
```

I added 777 and created a uploads dir, but the error persists. How do I find the path that needs to either be corrected or created?

Answer (score 21):

Change owner of `upload/` to `www-data:www-data` and also chmod to `755`

Comment: `chown -R www-data:www-data folder` this worked for me!

Comment: `chown -R <username> <folder>`

Answer (score 10):

Looks like it doesn't know where `upload/` is. Make sure you have the full path in your statement. For example, if upload directory is actually located in `/var/upload`, then make sure that is in your statement, not just `upload`/.

Answer (score 8):

Log into your ftp and confirm the following:

- The folder exists, check for spellings
- Check the properties of the folder and make sure the permissions have read+write `0666`
- Make sure the file is within your public html root, otherwise double check the owner of the file, and make sure PHP Has read / write access to it.

looking at the log:

```
Unable to move '/tmp/php6wlOg1' to    'upload/110216104651_00134_smooth_1440x900.jpg'
```

It seems to me that its looking in your root directory as `upload/110216....` should be `path.to/public_html/upload/110216....`

If none of the above work, please post your line of code that has `move_uploaded_file` on.

Comment: When Checking spelling also check that the case (capitals) is the same. Linux is case sensitive with file and directory names.

Answer (score 3):

It's trying to move the file to `upload/` not `uploads/`, make sure the directory exists and is writable.

Answer (score 3):

Provided, there are no spelling mismatches, give your upload directory (that directory ONLY) all user rights `sudo chmod a+rwx /path/to/folder`, that should fix the problem easily.
For a quick further read about permissions in Ubuntu, check [here](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/give-permissions-ubuntu-33174.html).