# Running into a problem when trying to upload a file with php script

Tags: php, linux, amazon-web-services, apache, ubuntu

I'm trying to make a website that processes .mp4 files. It worked fine when I ran it on my windows machine using XAMPP but since moving it to an ubuntu server I'm running into problems.

This is what the relevant code looks like (used this as a template https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp):

```
if ($uploadOk == 0) 
{
  if ($errorType == 1)
  {
    echo "Your file was not uploaded because it is not of type .mp4";
  }
  // if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
  if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    echo "\nThe file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
  } 
  else 
  {
    echo "An unknown error occured when uploading your file.";
  }
}
```

When I try to upload the file, it echos "An unknown error occured when uploading your file."

I've tried changing the directory permissions:
`sudo chown $USER -R /var/www`
`sudo chgrp www-data -R /var/www`
`sudo chmod 0751 -R /var/www`

I've also tried changing temporary file directory in php.ini to something under `/var/www` as suggested in another post.

Thanks in advance.

Update:
Following the advice from the comments I checked my `error.log` file:
`PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move`
Following this, I tried:

```
sudo chown ubuntu /var/www/html/Anamorphiser/uploads/
sudo chown ubuntu /var/www/html/tmp/

sudo chmod -R 0755 /var/www/html/Anamorphiser/uploads/
sudo chmod -R 0755 /var/www/html/tmp/
```

This didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Check your PHP error log for the actual error.

Comment: You are not showing us the code that initialises `$uploadOK`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PHP: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023181/php-move-uploaded-file-unable-to-move)

Answer here worked for me.
`chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/your/upload/folder/`